# How to restrict the number of raws after Columns to Raws conversion?

Tags: python, pandas

My data is like this:
[image: raw_data]

When I'm processing column-to-row conversion,I find the pandas method DataFrame.explode().But the 'explode' will increase raws by multiple the number of different values of columns.In this case,it means that the number of rows is 3(diffent values of Type) multiple 2(different values of Method) multiple 4(different values of Object),that is 24 rows for each title and name.What I want is like this:[image: wanted_data]
For each title and name,the number of rows is the maxium of different values of other three coulmns(Type,Method,Object).In this case,it is 4,not 24.
Is there any method or technique in Python could do this?

I find the method DataFrame.explode() will increase raws by multiple the number of different values of columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @Timeless approach:

```
def explode_uneven(df, subset=[]):
    def exp_dedup(s):
        s2 = s.str.split('[.,]\s*').explode()
        idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(s2.groupby(level=0, sort=False).cumcount().reset_index())
        return s2.set_axis(idx)
    keep_cols = list(df.columns.difference(subset))
    tmp = df.set_index(keep_cols, append=True)
    return pd.concat([exp_dedup(tmp[c]) for c in tmp], axis=1
                    ).reset_index(keep_cols).loc[df.index, list(df)]

# uncomment the last bit to remove the deduplication
out = explode_uneven(df, ['Type', 'Method', 'Object'])#.droplevel(-1)
```

Output:

```
          Title   Name Type Method Object
level_0 0                                
0       0  xxxx    Tom  abf      A      F
        1  xxxx    Tom   fe      B      Z
        2  xxxx    Tom   fa    NaN      E
        3  xxxx    Tom  NaN    NaN      G
1       0  yyyy  Jerry   ad      A      G
        1  yyyy  Jerry   fa      C      C
        2  yyyy  Jerry  NaN      D      X
        3  yyyy  Jerry  NaN      E    NaN
```

Comment: explode_deduplicate() seems undefined

Comment: @KevinSong this was a typo, I forgot to change the name, see update

Comment: yeah，now it‘s useful

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)/[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
out = (pd.concat(
            [df.set_index(["Title", "Name"])
                 .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).str.split(r",\s*"))
                 .pipe(lambda df_: df_[col].explode().to_frame())
                 .assign(idx=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
                 .set_index("idx", append=True) for col in ["Type", "Method", "Object"]
            ], axis=1).sort_index().droplevel(2).reset_index()
      )
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

  Title   Name Type Method Object
0  xxxx    TOM  abf      A      F
1  xxxx    TOM   fe      B      Z
2  xxxx    TOM   fa    NaN      E
3  xxxx    TOM  NaN    NaN      G
4  yyyy  Jerry   ad      A      G
5  yyyy  Jerry   fa      C      C
6  yyyy  Jerry  NaN      D      X
7  yyyy  Jerry  NaN      E    NaN
```